# The right way to move a data-only docker container from one machine to another

Tags: virtualization, docker, boot2docker

I have a database docker container that is writing its data to another data-only container. The data-only container has a volume where it stores the data of the database. Is there a "docker" way of migrating this data-only container from one machine to another? I read about docker save and docker load but these commands save and load images, not containers. I want to be able to package the docker container along with its volumes and move it to another machine.

Answer (score 5):

Checkout the [flocker](https://github.com/ClusterHQ/flocker) project. Very interesting solution to this problem, using ZFS to snapshot and replicate the storage volume between hosts.

Comment: What's the speed of such solution when you migrate a database? It can cause a big downtime to migrate a container with a database. And also what happens, if a host, running a service with associated data container physically goes down? I think in this case data will not migrate to another host.

Comment: @FractalizeR I recommend reading the flocker documentation and blog. It describes Flocker's unique "2 phase push" approach to data migration. Designed to cater for exactly the use case you're outlining. See: https://clusterhq.com/blog/introducing-flocker-0-2-faster-db-migrations-env-variables-multi-node-links/