# Move docker data volume containers between CoreOS hosts

Tags: linux, deployment, docker, orchestration, coreos

For some scenarios a clustered file system is just too much. This is, if I got it right, the use case for [the data volume container pattern](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/). But even CoreOS needs updates from time to time. If I'd still like to minimise the down time of applications, I'd have to move the data volume container with the app container to an other host, while the old host is being updated.

Are there best practices existing? A solution mentioned more often is the ["backup" of a container](http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/managing_deis/backing_up_data/) with `docker export` on the old host and `docker import` on the new host. But this would include scp-ing of tar-files to an other host. Can this be managed with [fleet](https://coreos.com/blog/cluster-level-container-orchestration/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The right way to move a data-only docker container from one machine to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730852/the-right-way-to-move-a-data-only-docker-container-from-one-machine-to-another)

Comment: I hope not. My question is CoreOS specific and I hope fleet can be utilised to orchestrate the process. That being said, answers from the other question could indeed apply to CoreOS as long as they don't collide with the design of CoreOS.

Comment: I think the right solution to suggest here is going to be application specific. What kind of data are you managing in the docker volume and what service are you trying to minimize downtime for?

Comment: @jkingyens Well, I'm not sure, but I don't think that this is application specific. If you want to manage data persistently with data volume containers, it doesn't matter if you store uploaded images, databases or something else in it. As soon as one host goes down (e.g. for an update or due to down-scaling), the data volume container has to be migrated to an other host.

Comment: @brejoc Fair enough. I don't think you will be able to do this at the docker container layer though. Docker volumes are more fine grained and associated with containers. I think what you are looking for is a way to remount network attached storage when a machine goes down. CoreOS can help you do this. And no doubt you could use fleet to do this as well. It might be cloud provider specific though. Is this the road you want to go down?

Comment: @brejoc I think you're looking at something specifically designed to solve this problem (like Flocker) or it would be considered an application issue. For example using DB replication or NoSQL datastores which can tolerate losing the disk volumes associated with individual cluster members.

Comment: @brejoc +1, I think that a clustered file system as part of CoreOS really makes sense. Regarding volume containers - their real value would be when you could commit + push them (e.g - version control the data), which is not the case today.

Comment: @JRun & Mark - I guess you are right. At the moment there is no 'pure docker' solution to this scenario. If you provide your solution as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@brejoc, I wouldn't call this a solution, but it may help:

Alternative 
1: Use another OS, which does have clustering, or at least - doesn't prevent it. I am now experimenting with CentOS.
2: I've created a couple of tools that help in some use cases. First tool, retrieves data from S3 (usually artifacts), and is uni-directional. Second tool, which I call 'backup volume container', has a lot of potential in it, but requires some feedback. It provides a 2-way backup/restore for data, from/to many persistent data stores including S3 (but also Dropbox, which is cool). As it is implemented now, when you run it for the first time, it would restore to the container. From that point on, it would monitor the relevant folder in the container for changes, and upon changes (and after a quiet period), it would back up to the persistent store.

Backup volume container: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/yaronr/backup-volume-container/
File sync from S3: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/yaronr/awscli/
(docker run yaronr/awscli aws s3 etc etc - read aws docs)

Comment: @brejoc, thanks. It will be nice if you try out backup-volume-container and give me your thoughts. So far a lot of people have downloaded but I received no comments, so I have no way of knowing if people really find it useful